# retry does not cause ajax call to be retried when Observable is retried

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, redux-observable

Based on `redux-observable` I have this epic:

```
export const someEpic = action$ => {
  return action$.pipe(
    ofType('FETCH_DATA'),
    switchMap(({ payload: { filter, bookingCenter } }) => {
      return concat(
        of(searchInProgress()),
        from(
          ApiManager.call('/v1/some-data', {
            method: 'GET',
            schema: false,
            params: {
              term: filter,
              bookingCenter,
            },
          })
        ).pipe(
          map(response => {
            if (!response) throw 'No result';
            return response;
          }),
          map(({ _embedded }) => updateResult(_embedded)
        )
      ).pipe(retry(2));
    })
  );
};
```

As you can see, I have a retry operator. Basically if server returns no response, I throw an error and retry is happening.

However, it is working only partialy i.e. in console I see that `searchInProgress` action is dispatched, however second observable created with `from` is not being executed once again.

`ApiManager.call` is returning regular `fetch` API Promise.

What is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz demo?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `defer` that will defer creation of observable from `Promise`:

```
    defer(() =>
      ApiManager.call('/v1/some-data', {
        method: 'GET',
        schema: false,
        params: {
          term: filter,
          bookingCenter,
          limit: 500,
        },
      })
    )
```